# Как сделать проверку совпадения паролей на jQuery.validity?

Tags: jquery

[jQuery.validity](http://validity.thatscaptaintoyou.com/).

```
<input type="password" class='reg-inp' id='password' name='password' >
<input type="password" class='reg-inp' id='confirm_password' name='confirm_password' >
```

Comment: Неужели те кто юзают jquery не могут сделать простую валидацию без стороннего плагина?О_о

Печалько да и только

Comment: без проблем дал бы если был бы вопрос как реализовать валидацию, вопрос же стоит о плагине jquery, ответа на ваш вопрос я не знаю, а гуглить вместо вас я не собираюсь, еще вопросы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проверка без плагинов. Форма ввода паролей

```
<form method="post" name="formZ" id="formZ" action="">
  <fieldset>
    <input type="password" name="passwordX" id="passwordX" />
    <input type="password" name="passwordY" id="passwordY" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Код для сверки значений:

```
$("#submit").click(function () {
    $(".error").hide();
    var valueX = $("#passwordX").val();
    var valueY = $("#passwordY").val();
    if (valueX != valueY) {
        alert("Passwords do not match.");
    }
});
```

Теперь проверка с [плагином](http://validity.thatscaptaintoyou.com/Demos/index.htm#Equal):

```
$("input[type='password']")
    .equal("Passwords do not match.");
```

Comment: Нашли инфу где? ТС утверждает что в гугле инфы нет